# MYSQL Procedure for while loop to add date

Tags: mysql, database, while-loop, automation

I am creating a table in mysql that needs to add incrementing date with a 3 hour interval between 2000-01-01 00:00:00 through 2020-01-01 00:00:00.

I created a table my_table with he primary key as time_key.
I made this procedure to create a while loop to insert the dates into table.

```
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE loop_date()
    -> BEGIN 
    -> SET @dateStart DEFAULT '2021-01-01 03:00:00';
    -> WHILE (dateStart < '2020-01-01 00:00:00') DO
    -> INSERT INTO my_table(time_key) VALUES (dateStart);
    -> set dateStart = dateStart + INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
    -> END WHILE;
    -> END;
    -> //
    -> DELIMITER;
 
    -> CALL loop_date();
```

I am getting an error 1054 unknown column 'dateStart' in field list

Comment: Could you post the error that you are getting?

Comment: I figured out the issue was using declare and changed it to set. However now that I have changed that I am getting a new error ERROR 1053 unknown column 'dateStart' in field list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I noticed is dateStart needs to have a data type in the DECLARE statement. In this case it should be DATETIME. Also the dateStart is larger than the value in while statement. So the while loop never executes.

Try this instead:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE loop_date()
BEGIN
    DECLARE dateStart DATETIME DEFAULT '2019-01-01 03:00:00';
    
    WHILE (dateStart < '2020-01-01 00:00:00') DO
        INSERT INTO my_table(time_key) VALUES (dateStart);
        SET dateStart = dateStart + INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
    END WHILE;
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL loop_date();
```

For me doing 1 year difference took 9.57 seconds.

UPDATE: This was in response to your original question which has been changed.

Comment: thank you this solved my problem I meant to put the default year as 2000. Took a minute and 30 seconds to run!